# How to select from multiple tables in a group by query?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have some database tables containing some documents that people need to sign. The tables are defined (somewhat simplified) as follows.

```
create table agreement (
    id integer NOT NULL,
    name character varying(50) NOT NULL,
    org_id integer NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT agreement_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
    CONSTRAINT org FOREIGN KEY (org_id) REFERENCES org (id) MATCH SIMPLE
)

create table version (
    id integer NOT NULL,
    content text NOT NULL,
    publish_date timestamp NOT NULL,
    agreement_id integer NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT version_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
    CONSTRAINT agr FOREIGN KEY (agreement_id) REFERENCES agreement (id) MATCH SIMPLE
)
```

I skipped the org table, to reduce clutter. I have been trying to write a query that would give me all the right agreement information for a given org. So far, I can do

```
SELECT a.id, a.name FROM agreement AS a
JOIN version as v ON (a.id = v.agreement_id)
JOIN org as o ON (o.id = a.org_id)
WHERE o.name = $1
GROUP BY a.id
```

This seems to give me a single record for each agreement that belongs to the org I want and has at least one version. But I need to also include content and date published of the latest version available. How do I do that?

Also, I have a separate table called signatures that links to a user and a version. If possible, I would like to extend this query to only include agreements where a given user didn't yet sign the latest version.

Edit: reflected the need for the org join, since I select orgs by name rather than by id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Postgresql has [Window Functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/tutorial-window.html).
Window functions allow you to operate a sort over a specific column or set of columns. the rank function returns the row's place in the results for the sort.  If you filter to just where the rank is 1 then you will always get just one row and it will be the highest sorted for the partition.

```
select u.id, u.name, u.content, u.publish_date from (
SELECT a.id, a.name, v.content, v.publish_date, rank() over (partition by a.id order by v.id desc) as pos
FROM agreement AS a
JOIN version as v ON (a.id = v.agreement_id)
JOIN org as o ON (o.id = a.org_id)
WHERE o.id = $1
) as u
where pos = 1
```

Comment: Just tried it, gives me "column "pos" does not exist"

Comment: did you have it as rank() over (partition by a.id order by v.id desc) as pos?

Comment: because the column doesn't exist I needed to wrap it.  I keep forgetting postgres is picky like that.

Comment: Now I get `missing FROM-clause entry for table "a"`

Comment: Sorry, I replaced the a and v in the outside select with u. That worked, but it gives me every possible version, it doesn't filter correctly.

Comment: you have the where pos = 1 at the end?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171642/discussion-between-lamorach-and-mad-wombat).

Answer (score 2):

You can use a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT a.id, a.name, v.*
FROM agreement a JOIN
     version v
     ON a.id = v.agreement_id
WHERE a.org_id = $1 AND
      v.publish_date = (SELECT MAX(v2.publish_date) FROM version v2 WHERE v2.agreement_id = v.agreement_id);
```

Notes:

- The `org` table is not needed because `agreement` has an `org_id`.
- No aggregation is needed for this query.  You are filtering for the most recent record.
- The correlated subquery is one method that retrieves the most recent version.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT a.id, a.name, max(v.publish_date) publish_date FROM agreement AS a
JOIN version as v ON (a.id = v.agreement_id)
JOIN org as o ON (o.id = a.org_id)
WHERE o.id = $1
GROUP BY a.id, a.name
```

Comment: Could you give an explanation for the OP on what he did wrong, what you did to fix it?

Comment: One correction, you don't need to join to the org table if you are just querying by org.id. Just query where a.org_id = $1

Comment: Just added max publish date off the version table - didn't change any join structure

Comment: Sorry, org join is there because I actually select org by name, wanted to simplify the query for the question. I just tried this solution and I get `column "v.content" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function`